# Jquery simple image zoom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jquery (core and ui), and I'm trying to do the following effect (which happens on many and many websites that have images):

[image]

Is it the Show + Size?

Comment: I believe it's called a lightbox, there are many plugins for it.

Comment: thank you @pimvdb :),
please answer the question too so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That effect is called a 'lightbox'. There are many plugins, including ones for jQuery, and there are quite alot of variations too.

The first result for 'lightbox jquery' results in this one, which isn't too bad at first sight:

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 3):

pick your favourite :)

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/

This is a nice resource for galleries. Search for more on your favourite browser.